# Вывод информации по индексу

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

Как вывести информацию о файле зная только его индекс в системе?

Comment: что за «индекс»? [inode, что ли?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35292/110559)

Comment: Ещё обратите внимание, что нет единого "индекса в системе". Есть номер инода на файловой системе, который уникален только в пределах одной файловой системы. То есть на машине может быть более одного файла с одинаковым номером инода, если они расположены на разных файловых системах.